# ActiveMQ producer waiting indefinitely for a valid connection

Tags: activemq-classic

We are facing an issue while producing message to an ActiveMQ 5.15.4 broker.
The thread trying to produce the message is blocked indefinitely:

```
Thread 464: (state = BLOCKED)
- java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
- org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.oneway(java.lang.Object) @bci=370, line=620 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(java.lang.Object) @bci=12, line=68 (Interpreted frame)
```

It seems that the `FailoverTransport` object is waiting to get valid connection (transport object not null) but the reconnection task is never launched.

Any idea how we can reach that situation and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, we didn't face the issue recently. We changed the connection factory and it seams to have solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end we did several actions and we didn't face the issue since then:

- Switch from CachingConnectionFactory to PooledConnectionFactory
- Use a dedicated connection factory for message senders distinct from the one used by the listeners
- Define one JmsTemplate per destination, and set the defaultDestination
  only once. (we used to have only 1 JmsTemplate and the destination was defined in the send method)